# Running program with subprocesses with Java

Tags: java, cmd, exec

I need to run an external program written in C from my Java application. 
I'm trying to use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` with partial success. I execute program using String with path to .exe file and its arguments:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec(command);

BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));

        String line=null;

        while((line=input.readLine()) != null) {
            log.info(line);
        }

        int exitVal = pr.waitFor();
```

This would work just fine - program executes and sends information about its behavior to console. Problem is that external program tries to run other subprograms during its execution. So basically what I need to do is: I run `program.exe` with my Java application and `program.exe` runs `subprogram.exe`. Unfortunately, that's not the case, because `subprogram.exe` never starts in current situation. 
What should I do differently to make it work ? Thanks for any help.

It is not my decision to have it so complicated and I would be more than happy to have just one .exe file to execute, but I can't.

Comment: How d u say that subprogram.exe never starts if "This would work just fine - program executes and sends information about its behavior to console"

Comment: Well, subprogram.exe has it's own console output and nothing shows up from it. Besides, this subprogram takes some time to execute and makes some output files - I don't see any traces of its execution when I run it using Java application.

Comment: try to run it from cmd.exe i.e.the command prompt and see if its working well!

Comment: It was a great idea. When I was executing main program, I used absolute path to it. So cmd.exe was still in the folder which I executed it from. `program.exe` was executing subprograms with relative path, so cmd.exe was searching `subprogram.exe` in initial folder and not that one where `program.exe' was. Thanks a lot!

Comment: So shall I give it as the answer?

Comment: kindly my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run it from cmd.exe i.e.the command prompt and see if its working well.The console output should give you a trace of the program execution.